# android layout scrolling with gridview and RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I have layout with RecyclerView scrolling horizontally and gridview vertically.
but recyclerview dosen't scroll up in activity, leaving gridview scrolling vertically below horizontal recyclerview list.

i want recyclerview to be scrolled horizontally while whole layout vertically scrolling.

content_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.test.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_dash_board"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:scrollbars="vertical">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:scrollbars="none" />
        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
            android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:numColumns="2"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

grid_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/grid_item_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:background="#55000000"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

why you are using gridview in recycler view. it will not behave correctly. if you want a grid view you can use recyclerview as a grid view.
set you recycler view layout manger as StaggeredGridLayoutManager. use it like.

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2,StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
```

take a refreance from https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html

Answer (score 0):

Your main layout should be scroll view and your recycle view height should not match parent .

you need to set height of grid view dynamically based on number of children.